# C# WPF animation jumping and ending in wrong place

Tags: c#, wpf, animation

I got a problem with a few of my functions ...
The following one takes an object and simply moves it along the x-axis by a specified amount of pixels. (I got another on for the y-axis)

```
private void AnimObject_Horizontal( FrameworkElement p_Object, double p_X, int p_Millisec ) {
        // Find out the actual position on the screen
        Point l_Start = p_Object.TransformToAncestor( m_Canvas ).Transform( new Point( 0, 0 ) );

        // Adjust the position, subtracting the Margins, that are set at initialization, because the margin is automaticly added to the PathPoints by C# 
        l_Start.X -= p_Object.Margin.Left;
        l_Start.Y -= p_Object.Margin.Top;

        // Create the path for the object to follow. Moving horizontally is just a straight line, so I just need to set the StartPoint and add a single point, which will be the end
        PathGeometry l_PathGeo = new PathGeometry();
        PathFigure l_PathFigure = new PathFigure();
        l_PathFigure.StartPoint = new Point(l_Start.X, l_Start.Y);
        LineSegment l_LineSegment = new LineSegment( new Point(l_Start.X + p_X, l_Start.Y ), false);
        l_PathFigure.Segments.Add( l_LineSegment );
        l_PathGeo.Figures.Add( l_PathFigure );
        l_PathGeo.Freeze();

        // Create both DoubleAnimations that animate the X and Y value of the given Object
        Transform l_Transform_ = new TranslateTransform();
        DoubleAnimationUsingPath translateXAnimation_ = new DoubleAnimationUsingPath();
        translateXAnimation_.PathGeometry = l_PathGeo;
        translateXAnimation_.Duration = TimeSpan.FromMilliSeconds( p_Millisec  );
        translateXAnimation_.Source = PathAnimationSource.X;

        DoubleAnimationUsingPath translateYAnimation_ = new DoubleAnimationUsingPath();
        translateYAnimation_.PathGeometry = l_PathGeo;
        translateYAnimation_.Duration = TimeSpan.FromMilliSeconds( p_Millisec  );
        translateYAnimation_.Source = PathAnimationSource.Y;

        // Set the object as animationtarget and add Eventhandler (One is enough, because they will both end at the same time (Almost atleast)
        p_Object.RenderTransform = l_Transform_;
        Storyboard.SetTarget( translateXAnimation_, p_Object );
        translateXAnimation_.Completed += AnimationHorizontalComplete;

        // Start both animations
        l_Transform_.BeginAnimation( TranslateTransform.XProperty, translateXAnimation_ );
        l_Transform_.BeginAnimation( TranslateTransform.YProperty, translateYAnimation_ );
    }
```

While this one moves an object in a quarter circle:

```
private void AnimObject_LeftToBottom( FrameworkElement p_Object, double p_Radius, int p_Millisec ) {
        Point l_Start = p_Object.TransformToAncestor( m_Canvas ).Transform( new Point( 0, 0 ) );
        l_Start.X -= p_Object.Margin.Left;
        l_Start.Y -= p_Object.Margin.Top;

        // Convert 15 degrees to radians
        double l_Angle_15 = 15 * Math.PI / 180;

        PathGeometry l_Path = new PathGeometry();
        PathFigure l_Figure = new PathFigure();
        l_Figure.StartPoint = l_Start;
        PolyBezierSegment l_BezierSegment = new PolyBezierSegment();

        // Create a quarter-circle-path with beziersegmens. There will be the Startpoint and another point each 15 degrees to form a quarter-circle.             
        for ( int i = 1 ; i < 7 ; i++ ) {
            l_BezierSegment.Points.Add( new Point( l_Start.X + p_Radius * Math.Sin( l_Angle_15 * i ), l_Start.Y + p_Radius - p_Radius * Math.Cos( l_Angle_15 * i ) ) );
        }

        l_Figure.Segments.Add( l_BezierSegment );
        l_Path.Figures.Add( l_Figure );
        l_Path.Freeze();

        Transform l_Transform_ = new TranslateTransform();
        DoubleAnimationUsingPath translateXAnimation_ = new DoubleAnimationUsingPath();
        translateXAnimation_.PathGeometry = l_Path;
        translateXAnimation_.Duration = TimeSpan.FromMilliSeconds( p_Millisec  );
        translateXAnimation_.Source = PathAnimationSource.X;

        DoubleAnimationUsingPath translateYAnimation_ = new DoubleAnimationUsingPath();
        translateYAnimation_.PathGeometry = l_Path;
        translateYAnimation_.Duration = TimeSpan.FromMilliSeconds( p_Millisec  );
        translateYAnimation_.Source = PathAnimationSource.Y;

        p_Object.RenderTransform = l_Transform_;
        Storyboard.SetTarget( translateXAnimation_, p_Object );
        translateXAnimation_.Completed += AnimationLeftBotComplete;
        l_Transform_.BeginAnimation( TranslateTransform.XProperty, translateXAnimation_ );
        l_Transform_.BeginAnimation( TranslateTransform.YProperty, translateYAnimation_ );
    }
```

As you can see, I added "Completed"-Events to those functions and I have linked them up. I added an image to my canvas and when I press a button the image is moved along the x-axis first, then makes a quartercircle to the bottom and then moved along the y-axis.

My problem is:
The image starts at 100,100 and should move to 200,100 and as soon as it reaches this position, it should move down in a circle.
However shortly before reaching the 200,100 it jumps to the second animation startpoint. (Or it just doesnt end in the place where it should)
Take a look at the picture, it might help to understand what I want to say with my kinda broken english ;) 
[AnimationProblem on tinypic](http://de.tinypic.com/r/2vnp7wz/8)

Does anyone know a reason for this behaviour ?

Greetings and thanks in advance,
Shera

Comment: Totally off topic but that code is crying out for green text!

Comment: You mean comments ?
I removed them, because the post would have been even more long then ...

Comment: Comments are valuable for two people. Future you (you will forget how it works) and _anyone else_. Long posts are preferable to short ones with hard to read code :)

Comment: I had the comments, but not in english. Added them in english here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it myself.
For people who share this problem:

Following line of code is a bit confusing, because it's not working as intended (In my opinion at least).

```
Point l_Start = p_Object.TransformToAncestor( m_Canvas ).Transform( new Point( 0, 0 ) );
```

Even if I create an object at (100, 100) the result of the code above will be (108.3, 100). At first I thought the reason for that might be the border of the window (Even if I set 0,0 of the Canvas as refering point), but that's not the problem. If I enter fullscreen mode, it is still the same, so that's not the reason.
I don't know where the 8.3 comes from and I don't know if that problem exists just for me or if it is a different value at each computer.